# Eclipse Juno navigation of opened tabs with arrows

Tags: eclipse-juno

I've recently upgraded to Juno from Indigo. All it's ok but I can't find how to navigate trough opened tabs with arrows (example image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/542/img2ri.jpg/) instead of the list (example image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/155/img1nh.jpg/).

Anyone knows how to restore this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This in reality was a mistake, the arrows to navigate between tabs are provided by the plugin Extended VS Presentation which unfortunately isn't available in Eclipse Juno. I've tried to install it, but the modification does not take effect because the new Eclipse uses a different render engine. :(